# How to rightly check boolean values from Java Interop?

Tags: clojure

I was initially spooked by the result being returned by the 'not' and false? functions on a value that seems false. Learned an important lesson but still have the question in this post's title.. (Sorry for the long post)

Here is my REPL evaluation.  The function v always returns a consistent value for the same input, which is a boolean value returned from Java interop.

```
route-map
=> {PersistentArrayMap@8742}  size = 2
 {Keyword@10243}  -> {Route@10234} 
 {Keyword@10316}  -> {Route@10236} 

(def v (fn [r] (. calc valid-rte? r) ))     ; valid-rte is a java function returning a boolean
=> Var
 
(v (first (vals route-map)))
=> true

(not (v (first (vals route-map))))
=> false

(v (second (vals route-map)))       ;; this object (arg to v) is what I'm focused on
=> false

(not (v (second (vals route-map))))
=> false
```

Aha! the 'not' function is not negating the previous result to 'true' !
Probably because the object being returned by v is not `false' or 'nil' but something 'equal to it'.
Before we check on that let's compare the results of the previous 2 calls.

```
(= (v (second (vals route-map))) 
   (not (v (second (vals route-map)))) )
=> true
```

So 'not' took a falsey value and still returned a false! Let's make sure we got a false back from the call to v..

```
(= false (v (second (vals route-map))) )
=> true

(false? (v (second (vals route-map))) )
=> false
```

Aha! false? is not agreeing with the prior check either. Let's examine what types we have here..

```
(type (v (second (vals route-map))))
=> java.lang.Boolean

(type (not (v (second (vals route-map)))))
=> java.lang.Boolean

(type false)
=> java.lang.Boolean
```

Seeing the last result above (type false) is sure as heck going to scare newbies away from Clojure. After all the type being returned by v is same as that of false. So why don't 'not' and 'false?' behave as expected? Because the java.lang.Boolean object being returned by v is not strictly the value 'false' they are looking for.

```
(false? (Boolean. false))
=> false

(not (Boolean. false))
=> false

(not false)
=> true
```

The question remains: Is there a canonical 'Clojure' way to check a boolean value returned from a java Interop call? Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: `(.getClass false)` is `java.lang.Boolean`.

Comment: People do take umbrage that Boolean/FALSE is respected while additional Boolean objects made by calling the Boolean constructor are not.  At first it seems unprincipled.  The two principles that apply are (1) it would tax every "if" in every program to check exotic Booleans more closely, and Clojure should be tax-free; and (2) Oracle should fix the problem of exotic Booleans in Java. (For #2 we can cite a message from "Rich Hickey" to the Clojure Google Group, April 13, 2012.)